# what is the difference bewteen sonar.global.exclusions and sonar.global.test.exclusions

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I got asked today to explain the difference between **sonar.global.exclusions** and **sonar.global.test.exclusions** tags. According to the documentation found at http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

the difference should be:

- sonar.global.exclusions - to exclude source code files
- sonar.global.test.exclusions - to exclude unit test files

Are unit test files not excluded when pattern is only set in the global.exclusions? Are there any other differences between the scope of these two tags?

sonarqube 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests and Sources are treated as different kinds of thing in SonarQube. That's why you have different parameters to specify their locations

```
sonar.sources
sonar.tests
```

and why you have different properties to specify their exclusions.

Note also the difference between `sonar.global.exclusions` and `sonar.exclusions`. The former will apply to *all* projects, the latter only to the project on which it's set.